# PHP Find First Anchor Tag

Tags: php, html

How would I use PHP to find and echo just the first anchor tag in the following string?

```
<ul class="side-navigation">
<li><a href="/?id=12">What is RtII?</a></li>
<li><a href="/?id=13">RtII in NY</a></li>
<li><a href="/?id=14">The Tiers of RtII</a></li>
<li><a href="/?id=15">Tier A: Core</a></li>
<li><a href="/?id=16">Tier B: Supplemental</a></li>
<li><a href="/?id=17">Tier C: Intensive</a></li>
<li><a href="/?id=18">Useful Links</a></li>
<li><a href="/?id=19">Important Documents</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php">&laquo; Go Back</a></li>
</ul>
```

Basically I want to use php to eventually echo `<a href="/?id=12">What is RtII?</a>`. How would I do this?

Even better, how would I simply get just the `href="/?id=12`?

Comment: This doesn't answer anything?

Comment: @Cody what have you tried?

Comment: Which is why it's a comment, not an answer... it's a hint to learn how to use DOM - give a man a fish, he eats for a day. teach a man to fish, he eats for live. ... learn DOM operations, you'll never have to ask a question like this again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has the ability to go through the DOM.  Use something like this. The variable `$html` will be your html string.

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument;
$domDoc->loadHTML($html);

$anchor = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$first = $anchor->item(0);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions:

**PHP:**

```
preg_match("/href[^>]*/", $html, $result);
```

**Result:**

> `href="/?id=12"`